# Rdiff-backup ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/...[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/

Tags: linux, windows, bash, backup

I have built Rdiff- backup solution for my Windows server networkdrive. Windows drive is mounted to Ubuntu server 14.04 using Cifs - utils. 
/etc/fstab input to mount drive automatically:

```
//192.168.1.102/SMB kataloog /media/windows cifs credentials=/home/documents/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Im running backup with cronjob and bash script that i wrote for rdiff is this:

```
rdiff-backup --force -v9 --print-statistics --no-hard-links  --exclude-globbing-filelist $SCRIPT_PATH/backup.exclude $REMOTE_PATH $LOCAL_PATH/`date +%Y%m%d_backup` >/tmp/last_backup.txt 2>/tmp/last_backup_E.txt
```

--exclude-globbing-filelist looks like this:

- /media/windows/*BIN
- /media/windows/RECYCLER /media/windows/System\Volume\ Information
- **.laccdp
- **.ntx
- **.cdx

The error i get is:

```
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-2100480068-2371841968-4251168943-1002 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-2100480068-2371841968-4251168943-1002'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-2100480068-2371841968-4251168943-500 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-2100480068-2371841968-4251168943-500'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1109 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1109'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1110 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1110'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1112 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1112'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1113 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1113'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1114 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1114'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1115 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1115'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1116 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1116'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1117 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1117'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1118 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1118'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1119 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1119'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1120 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1120'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1121 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1121'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1122 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1122'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1123 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1123'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1124 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1124'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1125 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1125'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1126 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1126'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1127 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1127'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1136 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-1136'
Tue Aug 19 23:36:37 2014  ListError $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-500 [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/windows/$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-640597885-1395529562-3128210328-500'
```

Comment: Problem is: Rdiff dosn´t exclude the $RECYCLE.BIN folder. All ideas are welcome :)